# PHP mail() not received for Outlook 2007

Tags: php, email, gmail, outlook-2007, contact-form

I have a contact form that I'm writing using jQuery and PHP.  Below is the PHP bit, which works perfectly fine when I change the $youremail variable to my gmail account, but the emails are never received in my office Outlook account.
Is there something I'm missing?

```
<?php

  // Email Vars
      $youremail = "my_email@on_outlook2007.com";
      $headers = "From: $name <$email>\n";
      $subject =  "Subject Line Here";
      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
      $message_clean = html_entity_decode(stripslashes($message));

  // Format Email
      $email_format_cc =    $message_clean . "\n\n" . "___________________________________________________________________________" . "\n\n" . 
                          "Name: " . $name . "\n" .
                          "Company: " . $company . "\n" .
                          "IP Address: " . $ip . "\n" .
                          "Sent: " . $timestamp;
      $email_format    =  $email_format_cc . "\n" . 
                          "Page: " . $from_url;

      mail($youremail, $subject, $email_format, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: It is not dependable on the receiver address. Did you check the spam folder?

Comment: Yes, I checked the spam folder.  No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your server's mail log to see if/why gmail is bouncing the mail. PHP's `mail()` function is extraordinarily stupid and claims success even as the universe explodes around it.

Comment: Just proves how bad-ass `mail()` is, bad-asses never turn around to look at explosions.

Comment: How can I check my server's mail log?  Is there somewhere I can go on Outlook to do this?

Comment: Depends on your mail server in windows. On most unix system's, it's usually `/var/log/maillog`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're talking about.  I'm only familiar with the PHP part - are you talking about using the command prompt in Windows?

Comment: Depends on what kind of server your script is running on. If it's a unix server, then it'll have a mail server on the same server, and the mail log file is in /var/log/maillog. If it's a windows server, you'll have to find out what mail server is running there, and where it keeps it logs files. This is not stuff you can view in outlook.

Comment: It seems there is nothing wrong with the code, but it's a complete internal server issue.  Thanks for checking for me!